# Write R package build binary file on windows

Tags: r, binary, package, rcpp, armadillo

I am writting a package on R with windows 10.

My package includes `RcppArmadillo` and `BH`. I used `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` function. After that I edited the line linkingTo to that:

```
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, BH
```

I did that in order to add c++ file in src folder with depends on library BH.
Everything works very well and I get the source file "vMF_1.0.tar".
Now I want to build the binary (.zip) in order to share the package with other. I read many tutorials but the solutions proposed did not work with me.
For instance I used these commands line in my MSDOS

```
RCMD INSTALL -build vMF
R CMD --build --compile-both vMF_1.0.tar.gz
R CMD build --force --binary vMF
```

None of three does not solve my problem. I get that `--build` or `--binary` is not an option. 
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like either a typo or a copy-and-paste error. Instead of

```
RCMD INSTALL -build vMF
```

do

```
R CMD INSTALL --build vMF
```

i.e. insert a space between `R` and `CMD`, and two hyphens with `--build`.  If everything else fails, you can also upload to the [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org) service and have it build your Windows binary. You should get an email within half an hour containing a link to the build logs and artefacts—including your desired `.zip`.

Comment: Nice!
I lost many hours due to this. You helped me again Dirk. Thant you so much I used R CMD INSTALL --build vMF and it works.

Comment: Excellent.  It is worth finding the "right" tutorial, or getting familiar with the R Manuals.  They have all this info, it is simply a little hard to find at times ;-)

Comment: Ok, I saw that i can build the package with RStudio. But I do not know how tell to RSudio that the package depends on RcppArmadillo and BH. After checking the package, I edited the description file and added my Cpp files. But I get an error message : DLL file is not load or something like that, when I try to install

Comment: You do that in the `DESCRIPTION` file just how you do it on the command-line. No difference.

Comment: But in the command line I did not load a such DLL file. I do not know if that was done automatically

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to say. Load which DLL file?

Comment: Hi Dirk, I have another question on this topic. With Ubuntu, is it the same code to build binary for windows ? I work on ubuntu now and I need binary for Unix, Mac and Windows

Comment: Same source, different (non-portable) binaries. You need to reinstall from your sources.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am no sure that I understand. I have the package source .tar.gz on Linux. How can I get windows binary, Mac binary and Linux binary. I want to share the package with some friends who work under theses systems